# gensim/models/ldaseqmodel.py:217: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars

Tags: gensim

/Users/Barry/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gensim/models/ldaseqmodel.py:217: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
  convergence = np.fabs((bound - old_bound) / old_bound)

```
#dynamic topic model
def run_dtm(num_topics=18):
    docs, years, titles = preprocessing(datasetType=2)

    #resort document by years
    Z = zip(years, docs)
    Z = sorted(Z, reverse=False)
    years_new, docs_new = zip(*Z)

    #generate time slice
    time_slice = Counter(years_new).values()

    for year in Counter(years_new):
        print year,' --- ',Counter(years_new)[year]

    print '********* data set loaded ********'
    dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(docs_new)
    corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(text) for text in docs_new]

    print '********* train lda seq model ********'
    ldaseq = ldaseqmodel.LdaSeqModel(corpus=corpus, id2word=dictionary, time_slice=time_slice, num_topics=num_topics)

    print '********* lda seq model done ********'
    ldaseq.print_topics(time=1)
```

Hey guys, I'm using the dynamic topic models in gensim package for topic analysis, following this tutorial, https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/docs/notebooks/ldaseqmodel.ipynb, however I always got the same unexpected error. Can anyone give me some guidance? I'm really puzzled even thought I have tried some different dataset for generating corpus and dictionary.
The error is like this:

/Users/Barry/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gensim/models/ldaseqmodel.py:217: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
  convergence = np.fabs((bound - old_bound) / old_bound)

Answer (score 1):

The `np.fabs` error means it is encountering an error with NumPy. What NumPy and gensim versions are you using?

NumPy no longer supports Python 2.7, and Ldaseq was added to Gensim in 2016, so you might just not have a compatible version available. If you are recoding a Python 3+ tutorial to a 2.7 variant, you obviously understand a little bit about the version differences - try running it in a, say, 3.6.8 environment (you will have to upgrade sometime anyway, 2020 is the end of 2.7 support from Python itself). That might already help, I've gone through the tutorial and did not encounter this with my own data.

That being said, I have encountered the same error before when running `LdaMulticore`, and it was caused by an empty corpus.

Instead of running your code fully in a function, can you try to go through it line by line (or look at you DEBUG level log) and check whether your output has the expected properties: that, for example your corpus is not empty (or contains empty documents)?

If that happens, fix the preprocessing steps and try again - that at least helped me and  [helped with the same ldamodel error in the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gensim/3Z_xCjOKQyE).

PS: not commenting because I lack the reputation, feel free to edit this.

Answer (score 1):

This is the issue with the source code of **ldaseqmodel.py** itself.
For the latest **gensim** package(**version 3.8.3**) I am getting the same error at line 293:

```
ldaseqmodel.py:293: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
  convergence = np.fabs((bound - old_bound) / old_bound)
```

Now, if you go through the code you will see this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8vKr.jpg)

You can see that here they divide the difference between **bound** and **old_bound** by the **old_bound**(which is also visible from the warning)

Now if you analyze further you will see that at line 263, the **old_bound** is initialized with **zero** and this is the main reason that you are getting this warning of **divide by zero encountered**.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnJHM.jpg)

For further information, I put a print statement at line 294:

```
print('bound = {}, old_bound = {}'.format(bound, old_bound))
```

The output I received is: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81yP8.png)

*So, in a single line you are getting this warning because of the source code of the package **ldaseqmodel.py** not because of any empty document. Although if you do not remove the empty documents from your corpus you will receive another warning. So I suggest if there are any empty documents in your corpus remove them and just ignore the above warning of **division by zero**.*