# I get Runtime Warning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars and divide by zero encountered in double_scalars when using ldaseq

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, gensim, lda

When using the ldaseqmodel in gensim, I got the running time warning:

> D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\ldaseqmodel.py:1474:
> RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
> converged = np.fabs((lhood_old - lhood) / (lhood_old * total))
> D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\ldaseqmodel.py:293:
> RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
> convergence = np.fabs((bound - old_bound) / old_bound)

This is the code:

```
ldaseq = LdaSeqModel(corpus=corpus_comments, id2word=dictionary_comments,time_slice=time_docs, num_topics=5, chunksize=10,lda_model=model)
```

The dataset is about 50,000 article in blog.

Please help me ! Thank you so much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['invalid value encountered in double\_scalars' warning, possibly numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767409/invalid-value-encountered-in-double-scalars-warning-possibly-numpy)

Answer (score 0):

The first warning, that you are getting; i.e.

```
D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\ldaseqmodel.py:1474: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
converged = np.fabs((lhood_old - lhood) / (lhood_old * total))
```

is because of **empty documents** in your corpus. To resolve this first find out the empty documents in your corpus and then remove them from the corpus.

Now, for the second warning please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65088030/13043216) answer, I already explain it in detail there, hope it will help you.
In short, you are getting the second warning, i.e.

```
D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\ldaseqmodel.py:293: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
convergence = np.fabs((bound - old_bound) / old_bound)
```

because `old_bound` is initialized as **zero** in the source code of `ldaseqmodel` in `gensim` because of that in this expression `(bound - old_bound) / old_bound` you are actually dividing the upper part by zero, which leads to the warning. So you simply ignore that warning because after the first iteration the value of `old_bound` gets updated, so you will not see the warning again.